# Storybook Component-level css file not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, storybook

I created a react app using create-react-app, and added a button component, a css for the button. When I load the story for the button, the styles are not loaded for the button. Pasting below, the related files. Is there any configuration that I am to do, to get this up and running with styles?

[github repo for the project](https://github.com/akhiltheguitarist/StoryBook/tree/master/storybookapp)

Component: index.js

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './style.css';
class CustomButton extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <button className={styles.customButton}>Hello</button>     
        );
    }
}
export default CustomButton;
```

style.css:

```
.customButton {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(223, 19, 19);
}
```

Story file:

```
import React from 'react';
import CustomButton from '../../src/index';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';


const story = storiesOf("Custom button",module);

story.addWithJSX("simple",() => <CustomButton/>);
```

System info:

```
Environment Info:

  System:
    OS: Windows 7 6.1.7601
    CPU: (2) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2370M CPU @ 2.40GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.16.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.9.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 84.0.4147.125
  npmPackages:
    @storybook/addon-info: ^5.3.19 => 5.3.19
    @storybook/components: ^5.3.19 => 5.3.19
    @storybook/preset-create-react-app: ^3.1.4 => 3.1.4
    @storybook/react: ^5.3.19 => 5.3.19
```

Comment: It looks like your currently have no `main.js` which configures webpack css files? Where is the file?

Comment: I have linked my github repo above. All those files are available there. Repo: https://github.com/akhiltheguitarist/StoryBook

Comment: I meant the file `main.js` located under this dir https://github.com/akhiltheguitarist/StoryBook/tree/master/storybookapp/.storybook

Comment: I have added them within the config.js file. Storybook is loading for me. Just that the css is not applied to my component.

Comment: In order to configure webpack css you might have to put into the main.js file. Anyway I'll show you in the answer then

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to `storybook` works with `webpack`, you have to firstly create file `main.js` under the `.storybook` dir. Then add `style-loader` + `css-loader` loaders to resolve your `css` import. Keep in mind, enable `modules: true` option in `css-loader` to help you import your classes:

`.storybook\main.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async config => {
    // Remove the existing css rule
    config.module.rules = config.module.rules.filter(
      f => f.test.toString() !== '/\\.css$/'
    );

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true, // Enable modules to help you using className
        }
      }],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

Comment: Man, it worked! Thanks a lot. Previously I did try using main.js, and css-loader, but I didnt know that I had to remove existing css rule. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had to filter out the css rule too. They should highlight this in their docs somewhere, I wouldn't expect that I need to remove their own css rule, if they have a css rule I would expect importing css to work out of the box!

Answer (score 3):

tmhao2005's answer helps a lot.  Note however that this is probably duplicating some Webpack rule config from your main app, and things will potentially get out of sync if you decide to make tweaks or add other CSS loaders in the future.  For instance, if you decide to add `postcss-loader`, you'd need to remember to add it in both your app's Webpack config in `webpack.config.js` **and** your Storybook Webpack config in `.storybook/main.js` (hint: you will not remember!).

Here's a slightly cleaner tweaked version that tells Storybook to reuse your app's Webpack CSS rule config.  This version will stay in sync with your main app's Webpack rule:

```js
// .storybook/main.js

// Imports the app's Webpack Config (change this to require() style with older Node.js versions).
import appWebpackConfig from '../webpack.config.js';

const isCSSRule = (rule) => rule.test.toString() === '/\\.css$/';

module.exports = {
    ...
    webpackFinal: (config) => {
        // Removes the existing CSS rule.
        config.module.rules = config.module.rules.filter((rule) => !isCSSRule(rule));

        // Tells Storybook to use the same CSS rule config as our app.
        config.module.rules.push(appWebpackConfig.module.rules.find(isCSSRule));

        return config;
    }
    ...
};
```

I tested this with Storybook 6.0.21 and it's working pretty nicely.